# Which classical liberal economists promoted the privacy and secrecy of businesses?

Tags: history-economic-thought, classical-economics

Quinn Slobodian ([2018](https://books.google.com/books?id=vIPWDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&dq=%22the%20idea%20of%20businessmen%20opening%20their%20account%20books%20beyond%20the%20firm%20represented%20a%20revision%20of%20the%20classical%20liberal%20vision%22)) writes:

> the idea of businessmen opening their account books beyond the firm represented a revision of the classical liberal vision. The privacy of the businessman was no longer sacred.

(This quote is in the context of Hayek and Mises's efforts in trying to set up the Austrian Business Cycle Research Institute and "to overcome the life-threatening secretiveness of Austrian enterprises and organizations.")

I was surprised by the above quote. I don't think I've ever come across Adam Smith or other "classical" economists promoting the "sacred" privacy of the businessman.

So, which economists advocated ideas that would justify the above quote?